# How to make a paragraph from a line starting with plus sign (+)

Tags: php, regex, parsing, text

I'am doing a simple text editor that I need to handle creating paragraphs.

Paragraphs will be in WikiDot Syntax, long story short what i need to change:

```
+ paragraph 1
```

changes to 
    < h1>paragraph< /h1>

```
++ subparagraph 1
```

changes to 
    < h2>subparagraph< /h2>

How do this in PHP?

Comment: what's the delimiter between paragraphs? newline (\n)?  double newline (\n\n)?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. WikiDot is open source and their parser is freely available. Use that instead.

Comment: @lonesomeday No, i don't want to have more code to maintain that i need for now. But surely if I will need to expand functonality I will do what you write. Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on @CrayonViolent's (in cases where the first replace interrups the second):

```
<?php
  $content = "Hello, world

+ Big Heading

++ Smaller heading

Additional content";

   function r($m){
     $tag = "h".strlen($m[1]);
     return "<{$tag}>{$m[2]}</{$tag}>";
   }
   $content = preg_replace_callback('/^(\+{1,6})\s?(.*)$/m','r', $content);

   echo $content;
?>
```

Also added the `m` (multi-line) flag to the regex for a little better matching, and will only do headers `<h1>`~`<h6>`.

Working example can be located [here](http://ideone.com/uTRKZ)

Answer (score 2):

```
$content = preg_replace ("~^\+\+(.*?)\n\n~",'<h2>$1</h2>',$content);
$content = preg_replace ("~^\+(.*?)\n\n~",'<h1>$1</h1>',$content);
```

Comment: Thank you, + works, but ++ not for ex. when i input: + Header\n\n++ Header 2

Comment: Thank you but Brad provided full solution, but i upvote your answer a a important part.